# Why can't I accept my own answer straight away?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer

I had a question, nobody else posted any answers, and I worked out the solution myself.

Why do I have to wait 24 hours to accept my own answer. When I don't have to wait before accepting anybody else's answer?

Comment: You do have to wait 15 minutes before you can accept an answer after it is posted IIRC.

Comment: @rene I never check back often enough to notice that :)